# How to set GRASS GIS environment variables in MacOS?

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script

I'm trying to use `grass.script` and `grass_session` in a standalone python script on my MacOS device, but I always get error messages that tells me specific environment variables aren't set in the right way:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script: /Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/, set the right one using the GRASSBIN environm. variable
```

```
RuntimeError: GRASS GIS start script: /Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/MacOS/grass.sh --config path, return as GISBASE a directory (Rebuilding Addon HTML manual pages index...
    Rebuilding Addon menu...
    /Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources) that do not exist.
```

I already tried a lot of different environment variable combinations without success:

```
export GRASSBIN="/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/MacOS/Grass.sh"
```

```
export GRASSBIN="/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/"
```

```
export GISBASE=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources
```

If I'm running the desktop version of GRASS GIS and execute the `env` command in the shell, I'm getting the following ouput:

```
MANPATH=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/docs/man:/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/docs/man:/opt/homebrew/share/man:
GRASS_PYTHON=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/python3
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
GISBASE_SYSTEM=/Library/GRASS/8.2
GRASS_GNUPLOT=gnuplot -persist
GRASS_PAGER=more
GISRC=/var/folders/tb/v92zl5yn4wx7503j9y4k5tls9gd4by/T/grass8-jonas.frei-44418/gisrc
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=
TMPDIR=/var/folders/tb/v92zl5yn4wx7503j9y4k5tls9gd4by/T/grass8-jonas.frei-44418
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=443
MallocSpaceEfficient=0
MallocNanoZone=0
TERM_SESSION_ID=6FC3C0CC-BF3B-460B-BA15-20E31299E75B
PYTHONEXECUTABLE=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/python
HISTFILESIZE=
USER=jonas.frei
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Coegc0wRwg/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x52F6917E:0x0:0x0
GISBASE=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources
PATH=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/scripts:/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/bin:/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/scripts:/Users/jonas.frei/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/jonas.frei/miniconda3/bin:/Documents/programms/brew/bin:/Users/jonas.frei/Documents/programms/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/scripts:/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/bin:/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/scripts:/Users/jonas.frei/.pyenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/jonas.frei/miniconda3/bin:/Documents/programms/brew/bin:/Users/jonas.frei/Documents/programms/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:${PATH}:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
LD_RUN_PATH=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/lib
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
PWD=/Users/jonas.frei
GIS_LOCK=44418
GRASS_PROJSHARE=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/share/proj
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
GDAL_DATA=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/share/gdal
GRASS_HTML_BROWSER_MACOSX=-b com.apple.helpviewer
GRASS_VERSION=8.2.0
GRASS_FONT_CAP=/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/etc/fontcap
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
HOME=/Users/jonas.frei
SHLVL=4
PYENV_SHELL=bash
GRASS_HTML_BROWSER=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/etc/html_browser_mac.sh
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
PYTHONPATH=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/etc/python
LOGNAME=jonas.frei
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
GRASS_ADDON_ETC=/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/etc:/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons/etc
GISBASE_USER=/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
GRASS_ADDON_BASE=/Users/jonas.frei/Library/GRASS/8.2/Addons
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: Are you setting the environment variables at the start of your python script? i.e. `os.environ['GRASS_BASE']=....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
export GRASSBIN=/Applications/GRASS-8.2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/grass
```